# Handling 401 in axios when using both interceptors and transformResponse

Tags: javascript, axios, interceptor

I have a method for fetching data from server, basically just another GET request. However I use `transformResponse` in order to modify data to suit my needs.

Also I have interceptor for dealing with 401 error responses.

The thing is, when server sends 401 response on my GET request, `transformResponse` code runs and tries to modify server response, which is obviously is not what `transformResponse` expected. This leads to the situation when interceptor receives javascript error and doesn't get full http response (error.response returns undefined).

Here is two code samples.

Getting data from server:

```
 findOak() {
    console.log('find oak')
    return axios.get(`${baseURL}/`, {
      params: {
        is_oak: true
      },
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        console.log('transformResponse')
        return companyTransformer(response.data[0])
      }
    }).then(response => response.data)
  }
```

Setting up interceptors:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
      console.log('interceptor')
      console.log(error.response)
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401 && authenticated()) {
        logout()
        window.location.href = '/'
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }
    }
  )
```

So the `error.response` is undefined, instead of server response in holds the error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` which happens in transformResponse.

How to deal with this case?

Comment: Shouldn't the `response` variable in `transformResponse` have a status value you can check and then return the response if != 200

Comment: is there a reason why you cannot put transformation into chained `then()` instead of `transformResponse`?

Comment: @skyboyer indeed... :)

Comment: @richbai90 looks like skyboyer solution is simpler, since I won't need to use transformResponse at all